# Surjective isometry between normed spaces of different dimension

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two normed spaces with $\dim(X) < \dim(Y)$.  Can there be any surjective isometry between them?

Comment: No. Think Schroeder Bernstein. Isometry automatically implies injective.

Comment: Are you assuming the isometry is linear? The proof is easier for linear ones, but the result is true either way.